# Better way to write SQL where clause with date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a SQL Statement, shown below.  This is ultimately going to be used to populate a reporting table nightly with the days transactions.  When I run it without the

```
Cast(M._CreateDateTime as Date) = @StartDate
```

It takes 1:40.
With the function back in the where clause it takes over 10 minutes.

```
Declare @StartDate DAte = GetDate()

If Object_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#WinBack') is not null Drop Table #WinBack

Select
  M.HospitalMasterID
  ,M.TxnSite
  ,P.ClientID
  ,M.PatientID
  ,M.TxnDate as CallDate
  ,M.TxnCode
  ,M.EnteredMasterID
  ,U.UserName
  ,U.UserDept
Into
  #WinBack
From
  Avimark_OLTP.dbo.MedicalHistory as M
  Inner JoinAvimark_OLTP.dbo.Patient as P on
    M.HospitalMasterID = P.HospitalMasterID and
    M.PatientID = P.PatientID
  Left Outer Join RptSys.dbo.Ref_User as U on
    M.EnteredMasterID = U.UserMastID
Where
  Cast(M._CreateDateTime as Date) = @StartDate and
  M.TxnCode = 'RemCall' and
  U.UserName is not null
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this up?  I know it is the cast part that is killing it.

Thanks,

Comment: you can also SET READ Uncommitted at the top,if dirty read is not an issue.SET NoCount on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using function for a column makes SQL Server both cast every single row in the table it's comparing and preventing index usage, you should do it like this:

```
Declare @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date

set @StartDate = GetDate()
set @EndDate = dateadd(day, 1, @StartDate)

select 
   ... 
where 
    M._CreateDateTime >= @StartDate and 
    M._CreateDateTime < @endDate
```

Comment: Thanks will try that - right now I keep getting a Suspended on the Whoisactive so something else is going on with our server.

Comment: You should probably look at statistics io and query plan too, if there's something else that doesn't look ok.